# How to join two images into one with FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, tile

There are two images: *a.jpg* and *b.jpg*.

I just want to know how to join them into one image using `ffmpeg`.

How should I finish the `ffmpeg -i a.jpg -i b.jpg` command to get a *c.jpg* output image?

This is an example of what I am trying to achieve:

1. *a.jpg*

   [image: a.jpg]
2. *b.jpg*

   [image: b.jpg]
3. *c.jpg*

   [image: a.jpg and b.jpg side-by-side on one image]

Comment: You might consider changing the accepted answer since the current one is invalid.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

I think that [tile](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#tile) is your `ffmpeg` command.

You can find more [info](https://superuser.com/questions/625189/combine-multiple-images-to-form-a-strip-of-images-ffmpeg) on Superuser.

Try:

```
ffmpeg -i a.jpg -i b.jpg -filter_complex scale=120:-1,tile=2x1 output.jpg
```

Comment: I get a black box instead of the _b.jpg_ in the output.jpg when I use your command.

Comment: This method is invalid for joining images. Here's why: http://superuser.com/a/1091070/442991

Answer (score 42):

Use the [hstack](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#hstack) filter.

2 images:

```
ffmpeg -i a.jpg -i b.jpg -filter_complex hstack output.jpg
```

3 images:

```
ffmpeg -i a.jpg -i b.jpg -i c.jpg -filter_complex "[0][1][2]hstack=inputs=3" output.jpg
```

- If you want to vertically stack use `vstack` instead.
- See [Vertically or horizontally stack several videos using ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33764934/) for more examples.
- To change quality see [How can I output a good quality JPEG image from ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10234065/)

Comment: This works, if we have two files with same widthXheight, but what if we have two images with different widthXheight, how do we scale it and join them ??

Comment: @JitendarM See scale example in [Vertically or horizontally stack several videos using ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33764934/1109017)

Comment: thanks, will look into it.

Comment: I tried using this method for merging three images, but apparently, we need to make it in groups of two. It was enough for me, but do you know if there is a way to merge more than two images at once?  EDIT: just found out the answer to this in the thread that is mentioned at the beginning of this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552565/vertically-or-horizontally-stack-several-videos-using-ffmpeg

Answer (score 5):

#### Watch out! Dirty hacks ahead!

Pay attention to the [LordNeckbeard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37903609/4694621) since it is much better than the hacks of mine.

---

[Álvaro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24650100/4694621) didn't work for me so I did more research to solve the issue. This is what I've learnt:

I am going to use the following variables.

```
A_HEIGHT=458
A_WIDTH=370
B_HEIGHT=600
B_WIDTH=750
B_CROP_X=112
B_CROP_Y=0
A_IMAGE=a.jpg
B_IMAGE=b.jpg
B_IMAGE_SCALED=b-scaled.png
B_IMAGE_CROPPED=b-cropped.png
C_IMAGE_WITHOUT_A=c-without-a.png
C_IMAGE=c.png
```

### Scale and crop

In case your images are not of the same width and height.

This script scales B to be of the size as A.

```
# Scale.
ffmpeg -y -i ${B_IMAGE} -vf \
  scale=${A_HEIGHT}*${B_WIDTH}/${B_HEIGHT}:${A_HEIGHT} ${B_IMAGE_SCALED}

# Crop.
ffmpeg -y -i ${B_IMAGE_SCALED} -vf \
  "crop=${A_WIDTH}:${A_HEIGHT}:${B_CROP_X}:${B_CROP_Y}" ${B_IMAGE_CROPPED}
```

### Merge / join two images

```
ffmpeg -y -i ${B_IMAGE_CROPPED} -filter_complex tile=2x1 ${C_IMAGE_WITHOUT_A}
```

Now the `C_IMAGE_WITHOUT_A` lacks A; there is a black background instead. (You'll should get something similar to the picture below.)

[image: Example]

I have found a way to join those two images nevertheless:

```
ffmpeg -y -i ${C_IMAGE_WITHOUT_A} -i ${A_IMAGE} \
  -filter_complex overlay=${A_WIDTH}:0 ${C_IMAGE}
```