# Compress Images Using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

Kindly let me know if there is any method to compress image using FFMPEG

```
ffmpeg -i img.png imgOut.png
```

How to compress the output image or change the quality if it

Answer (score 22):

## PNG

Just use the default settings. PNG is lossless so there is no way to control the quality, but you can control the compression. You can use `-compression_level` for PNG output if you want **less** compression. Range is 0-100. Default is 100 which is most compression meaning that **the defaults provide the smallest output file size**.

Output a series of PNG images from a video. Files will be named `output_0001.png`, `output_0002.png`, `output_0003.png`, etc.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 output_%04d.png
```

Output a single PNG image from a video at around 00:02:00.

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:02:00 -i input.mp4 -frames:v 1 output.png
```

If you want additional processing refer to `pngcrush`, `optipng`, `advpng`, etc.

## JPEG

For JPG output see [How can I extract a good quality JPEG image with ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10234065/1109017)

Comment: if i use `ffmpeg -compression_level 50 -i thumb-intro.png imgOut.png` it gives
Codec AVOption compression_level () specified for input file #0 (thumb-intro.png) is not a decoding option.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Option placement matters. You're trying to apply it to the input. Move the option so it applies to the output. `ffmpeg [input options] -i input [output options] output`

Comment: This question is on top in google with `"Compress Images Using FFMPEG"` keyword. please add some info about JPEG in your answer too. thanks

Comment: @S.R I added a link to a JPG answer addressing that.

Comment: No, -pred mixed is much more important.

Comment: And no, range is 0-9. 10 and higher are bitperfect.

Answer (score -3):

PNG is a lossless image format, so you can't really toggle the compression ratio in any useful way. Typical options such as -b:v only apply to formats to which ratecontrol applies (e.g. most video codecs, or .jpg for images).

Comment: This is absolutely wrong.

Comment: PNG is a lossless image format, but you can cut off it's quality to reduce the size of the file by using some algorithms for example color degrade.