# How to extract frames with FFMpeg? (FFMpeg output is pixelated)

Tags: video, ffmpeg, converters, video-conversion, video-codecs

I want to extract frames from movies with ffmpeg.exe. But the output is very pixelated even if I use

> -qscale:v 1

Here is my command line:

```
ffmpeg -i^
    "d:\movies\snow flakes.mov"^ 
    -qscale:v 1^    
    d:\frames\frame%%03d.jpg^
    -hide_banner
```

The video is not pixelated in BSPlayer or VLC.

How to extract better quality frames from my videos?

Comment: Check if a png output looks ok (lossless). If yes, something with jpg is the problem. [Some other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225403/how-can-i-extract-a-good-quality-jpeg-image-from-an-h264-video-file-with-ffmpeg) here says qscale is only 2-31 for jpeg (okay: comments mention 1 is mapped to 2; so should not be the reason).

Comment: @sascha - Please Post your comment as an answer. I will accept it. The problem was the JPG

Comment: @sascha - the comments in that Question says that 0 and 1 are same as 2.

Comment: Yes, i edited my comment. I won't post an answer as i don't have any *good* reason for your observation (jpeg with q=2 so bad; although that's also dependent on your source).

Comment: @sascha - Qscale is irrelevant. What i mean is that your answer "change from jpg to png" solved my problem. If you post that as answer I will accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

specifically, had to tell ffmpeg to apply quality "2" for video:

```
ffmpeg -i^
    "d:\movies\snow flakes.mov"^ 
    -q:v 2^    
    d:\frames\frame%%03d.jpg^
    -hide_banner
```