# How can i create thumbnail and convert video into mp4 in php without ffmpeg?

Tags: php, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

I need to uploaded video convert into mp4 and also create thumbnail image. 
I am try with ffmpeg but many hosting provide not intalled ffmpeg. So now i need to that features without using ffmpeg i want do it. Any know ? How can i do without ffmpeg ?

Comment: You can ask for ffmpeg installation from your hosting provider or else you have ssh access then you can install ffmpeg manually.

Comment: Answer the questions or leave it. Please not give down vote. Because Goddady server not providing ffmpeg setup so i am facing this issue...

Comment: @Sathishkumar Rakkiasamy for that i need purchase Private Hosting it was too costly. And That is last option. Before why not try other solutions if have

Comment: How do you know I am one who down voted in this question?. I just tried to help you.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to "install" `ffmpeg` in the traditional sense.

Just [download an already compiled static build of `ffmpeg`](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) then point to it in your script using the full path.

A basic, unscripted thumbnail command:

```
ffmpeg -ss 30 -i input -vf scale=120:-1 -frames:v 1 -q:v 4 output.jpg
```

Also see:

- [FFmpeg Wiki: PHP](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/PHP)
- [How can I extract a good quality JPEG image from an H264 video file with ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10234065/1109017)