# Extract video thumbnail using PHP without ffmpeg

Tags: php, ffmpeg, thumbnails

The question is similar to: [Is there any way to create a video thumbnail through PHP without ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11383179/is-there-any-way-to-create-a-video-thumbnail-through-php-without-ffmpeg)
However, that thread is 6-year old and technologies have evolved since then.

Any way to extract a thumbnail from uploaded MP4 file using PHP?

Ffmpeg is great, but unfortunately unsupported on shared hosting accounts, requiring a dedicated server. And it's a kinda overkill to use ffmpeg's power just to generate a video preview picture.

Any other simple solution?

Comment: Not really. Implementing all kinds of video decoders in pure php would be tremendous work, require much more resources and ffmpeg already does it quickly and reliably.

Comment: Similar to [How can i create thumbnail and convert video into mp4 in php without ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48806958/how-can-i-create-thumbnail-and-convert-video-into-mp4-in-php-without-ffmpeg)