# How to extract good quality frames from a video and save them without compression?

Tags: python-3.x, video, ffmpeg, video-processing

How can I use ffmpeg and only extract the frames that does not have artifacts (e.g. compression artifacts) from a video and save them with good quality in jpeg format .

Comment: You can try [extracting only I-frames (key frames)](https://superuser.com/questions/669716/how-to-extract-all-key-frames-from-a-video-clip). Key frames are not necessarily the best quality frames, but they have the advantage that the artifacts are relatively bounded. In case you are looking for  an algorithm that finds the best quality frames, it's a different story... You should also look at: [How can I extract quality JPEG image from an H264 video file with ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225403/how-can-i-extract-a-good-quality-jpeg-image-from-an-h264-video-file-with-ffmpeg)

Comment: First you need a programmatic war to detect compression artifacts. I don't believe ffmpeg has a filter for that.

Comment: Show example image of normal frame and example of next frame with compression artefact. You can use FFmpeg to extract individual frames and pass them through your function of "check image quality" (decide what makes a "bad" image and then tell the machine to look for such pixels) and then save to JPG. Which part of that is the problem?

Comment: @VC.One can you provide a sample code that does that?