# Extract first frame of multi video streams video

Tags: ffmpeg

I am curious about how to use FFmpeg in order to extract the first frame of the first video stream from a multi-video stream file. 
What I have so far is:

`ffmpeg -i {mediaFile} -ss 0 -map 0:v -vframes 1 -f image2 firstFrame.jpeg`.

I am not sure about the `-map` part. How can be certain that I work on the first video stream? Is there a way to first filter streams by codec type, then select the first and then extract the frame?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -i {mediaFile} -map 0:v:0 -frames:v 1 firstFrame.jpeg
```

Add an input stream index to your `-map` as shown in the example above. `0:v:0` is `input #0:video:stream #0`. Note that `ffmpeg` starts counting from 0. If you wanted video stream #3, it would be `0:v:2`.

I removed the superfluous options from your command.

Also see

- [`-map` option documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options)
- [How can I extract a good quality JPEG image from a video with ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10234065/)