# Create multiple thumbnails from a video at equal times / intervals

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to create multiple thumbnails (ex. 12) from a video at equal times using ffmpeg.
So for example if the video is 60 seconds - I need to extract a screenshot every 5 seconds.

Im using the following command to get the frame in the 5ths second.

```
ffmpeg -ss 5 -i video.webm -frames:v 1 -s 120x90 thumbnail.jpeg
```

Is there a way to get multiple thumbnails with one command?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Get duration (optional)

[Get duration using `ffprobe`](https://superuser.com/a/945604). This is an optional step but is helpful if you will be scripting or automating the next commands.

```
ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 input.mp4
```

Example result:

```
60.000000
```

## Output one frame every 5 seconds

Using the [select](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#select_002c-aselect) filter:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "select='not(mod(t,5))',setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB" output_%04d.jpg
```

or

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "select='not(mod(t,5))'" -vsync vfr output_%04d.jpg
```

- Files will be named `output_0001.jpg`, `output_0002.jpg`, `output_0003.jpg`, etc. See [image muxer documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-2) for more info and options.
- To adjust JPEG quality see [How can I extract a good quality JPEG image from a video with `ffmpeg`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10234065/)

## Output specific number of equally spaced frames

This will output 12 frames from a 60 second duration input:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "select='not(mod(t,60/12))'" -vsync vfr output_%04d.jpg
```

You must manually enter the duration of the input (shown as `60` in the example above). See an automatic method immediately below.

## Using `ffprobe` to automatically provide duration value

Bash example:

```
input=input.mp4; ffmpeg -i "$input" -vf "select='not(mod(t,$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 $input)/12))'" -vsync vfr output_%04d.jpg
```

## With scale filter

Example using the [scale](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) filter:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "select='not(mod(t,60/12))',scale=120:-1" -vsync vfr output_%04d.jpg
```

Comment: Using `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "ffmpeg -i input.webm -vf "select='not(mod(t,60/12))'" -vsync vfr output_%04d.jpg` seems to produce only one frame - output_0001.jpg. I'm not sure what the `select='not(mod(t,60/12))` part does. I guess it is testing each frame ot figure if it should output it?

Comment: @AlexanderVakrilov What is the duration of `input.webm`?

Comment: It was about 44 seconds. I think the problem is that times of the frames are not on exact seconds. For example one frame might be at time 4.980s and the next may be on 5.020s. Both will not match the `not(mod(t,60/12))`

Comment: I ended up using `select='not(mod(n, 150}))` where 150 is the estimated total number of frames  (`duration*framerate`) devided by 12 (the number of thumbnails to generate). For 60 second video with 30 fps -> (60*30)/12 = 150

Comment: @AlexanderVakrilov Are you working with WebRTC inputs?

Comment: Yes. I actually process the video in browser using WebAssembly build of ffmpeg

Comment: @llogan, or anyone out there how to get only 10 frames always irrespective of video duration. let say if a video duration is `120` then i want to capture 10 frames like so `[0 or 12, 24,36,48,60,72,84,96,108,120]`. please help me with that logic

Comment: here i have posted a question too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73349722/how-to-generate-only-10-thumbnails-irrespective-of-video-duration-with-ffmpeg

Comment: @llogan This solution also only generates 1 file using the equally spaced frames code. I'm using a normal MOV file that is 118 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

```php
<?php

$ffmpegPath = exec('which ffmpeg'); $ffprobePath = exec('which ffprobe');

$command = "$ffprobePath -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 $input_video"; $video_duration = shell_exec($command);

$thumbnails_output = 'output%02d.png'; $command = "$ffmpegPath -i $input_video -vf fps=3/$video_duration $thumbnails_output"; 
shell_exec($command);

?>
```

Comment: What language is this? I think they were asking for a list of CLI commands, which your response contains, but not in a clear way