# Extract frame from secondary videostream FFMpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-capture, mkv

I work with FFMpeg and process some .mkv videos that can have more than one videostream. How I can extract frame from other videostream (not from primary)? I want to extract one frame from each videostream using FFMPeg. Any ideas?

Comment: You may want to look at: [FFmpeg's **Map** guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map). You likely want: `ffmpeg -i yourfile.mkv -map 0:1 -c copy output.mkv`. See if that gets the second stream.

Comment: Yes, it really works. Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Example input file layout:

- video #0:0
- video #0:1
- video #0:2
- audio #0:3
- audio #0:4

## Example: Output screenshot from video #0:2

From 30 second timestamp (`-ss 30`).

#### Absolute map

```
ffmpeg -ss 30 -i input.mkv -map 0:2 -frames:v 1 output.jpg
```

#### Relative map

Same result as above with this particular input. `0:v:1` is translated as "from input #0 choose video stream #1". **Note that `ffmpeg` starts counting from 0**, so video stream #1 is actually the 2nd video stream.

```
ffmpeg -ss 30 -i input.mkv -map 0:v:1 -frames:v 1 output.jpg
```

I prefer using this method because you can be lazy and not have to know the actual stream map numbers.

## Example: Output a screenshot from each video stream

```
ffmpeg -ss 30 -i input.mkv -map 0:v:0 -frames:v 1 output0.jpg -map 0:v:1 -frames:v 1 output1.jpg -map 0:v:2 -frames:v 1 output2.jpg
```

#### Also see

- [FFmpeg Wiki: Map](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map)
- [`-map` option documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options)
- [How can I extract a good quality JPEG image from a video file with `ffmpeg`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225403/how-can-i-extract-a-good-quality-jpeg-image-from-an-h264-video-file-with-ffmpeg/10234065#10234065)