# ffmpeg quality conversion options (video compression)

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, compression, video-processing, video-compression

**Can you provide a link, or an explanation, to the `-q:v 1` argument that deals with video/image quality, and compression, in ffmpeg.**

Let me explain...

```
for f in *
   do 
     extension="${f##*.}"
     filename="${f%.*}"
     ffmpeg -i "$f" -q:v 1 "$filename"_lq."$extension"
     rm -f "$f"
   done
```

The ffmpeg `for` loop above compresses all images and videos in your working directory, it basically lowers the quality which results in smaller file sizes (the desired outcome).

I'm most interested in the `-q:v 1` argument of this `for` loop. The `1` in the `-q:v 1` argument is what controls the amount of compression. But I can't find any documentation describing how to change this value of `1`, and describing what it does. Is it a percentage? Multiplier? How do I adjust this knob? Can/should I use negative values? Integers only? Min/max values? etc.

I started with [the official documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Video-Options) but the best I could find was a section on video quality, and the `-q` flag description is sparse.

> -frames[:stream_specifier] framecount (output,per-stream)
> Stop writing to the stream after framecount frames.
> .
> -q[:stream_specifier] q (output,per-stream)
>
> -qscale[:stream_specifier] q (output,per-stream)
> Use fixed quality scale (VBR). The meaning of q/qscale is codec-dependent. If qscale is used without a stream_specifier then it applies only to the video stream, this is to maintain compatibility with previous behavior and as specifying the same codec specific value to 2 different codecs that is audio and video generally is not what is intended when no stream_specifier is used.

Comment: What is the encoder you are using? If you don't know then what is the `$extension`?

Comment: @llogan I entered `extension` at the command line and nothing happened. I guess I don't understand the question.

Comment: `-q:v`/`-qscale:v` depends on the encoder. I wanted to know what encoder you were using to give an accurate answer. I asked for the extension (`.mp4`, `.mkv`, `.avi`, `.mov`, etc)  of the output file in case you were not sure which encoder you're using.

Comment: @llogan the output files are .mp4

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## `-q:v` is probably being ignored

You are outputting MP4, so it is most likely that you are using the encoder libx264 which outputs H.264 video.

`-q:v` / `-qscale:v` is ignored by libx264.

The console output even provides a warning about this: `-qscale is ignored, -crf is recommended.`

For more info on `-crf` see [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264).

## When can I use `-q:v`?

The MPEG* encoders (mpeg4, mpeg2video, mpeg1video, mjpeg, libxvid, msmpeg4) can use `-q:v` / `-qscale:v`.

See [How can I extract a good quality JPEG image from a video file with ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10234065/) for more info on this option.

Answer (score 3):

This option is an alias for `-qscale:v` which might be why you didn't encounter it during your research (eventhough my resultat came first with "ffmpeg q:v" on google).
This [link](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/MPEG-4) explains how the `qscale` option is not a multiplier or a percentage, it's a bitrate mode (so it's to bitrate). For a given encoder, the lower this number the higher the bitrate and quality. It usually spans from 1-31 but some encoders can accept a subset of this range.