# Record from camera, save to file, and acess last recorded frame

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to record video from a camera, save it to file, and at the same time have access to the last frame recorded.

One idea would be to use [ffmpeg's Multiple Outputs functionality](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Creating%20multiple%20outputs) where I split the stream into two, one gets saved to file, one spits out the last recorded frame (ideally, the frames won't need to be written to disk, but piped onwards for processing).

What I don't know is how to get ffmpeg to spit "the last frame" from a stream.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not just extract the last frame from the saved file?

Comment: I might misunderstand you, but the idea here is to have it live: so the camera records to the file, and while it is doing so, I want to "continuously" extract frames from that stream. So 1 or 5 frames per second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Output a video and continuously update an image every second

```
ffmpeg -i input.foo outputvideo.mp4 -r 1 -update 1 image.jpg
```

### Output a video and output a new image every second

```
ffmpeg -i input.foo outputvideo.mp4 -r 1 images_%04d.jpg
```

- Output will be named `images_0001.jpg`, `images_0002.jpg`, etc.

#### Also see

- [FFmpeg image muxer documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-2) for more info and options.
- [How can I extract a good quality JPEG image from a video file with ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10234065/)

Comment: Great info, thank you. Is there a good way to pipe the last frame from some input? Something like this?
`ffmpeg -i input_video.mp4 -r 1 -update 1 -f image2pipe -`

Comment: @12.yakir No need for `-update 1` if you are not outputting to a single image file. Use `ffmpeg -i input_video.mp4 -r 1 -f image2pipe -`