# FFmpeg decoding .mp4 video file

Tags: c, video, ffmpeg, mp4, libavcodec

I'm working on a project that needs to open .mp4 file format, read it's frames 1 by 1, decode them and encode them with better type of lossless compression and save them into a file.

Please correct me if i'm wrong with order of doing things, because i'm not 100% sure how this particular thing should be done. From my understanding it should go like this:

```
1. Open input .mp4 file
2. Find stream info -> find video stream index
3. Copy codec pointer of found video stream index into AVCodecContext type pointer
4. Find decoder -> allocate codec context -> open codec
5. Read frame by frame -> decode the frame -> encode the frame -> save it into a file
```

So far i encountered couple of problems. For example, if i want to save a frame using `av_interleaved_write_frame()` function, i can't open input .mp4 file using `avformat_open_input()` since it's gonna populate `filename` part of the `AVFormatContext` structure with input file name and therefore i can't "write" into that file. I've tried different solution using `av_guess_format()` but when i dump format using `dump_format()` i get nothing so i can't find stream information about which codec is it using.

So if anyone have any suggestions, i would really appreciate them. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to convert a .mp4 to a series of lossless still images?

Comment: Well i'm trying to split .mp4 file into frames, compress them and send them through a network. On the other end those frames will get concatenated back into a .mp4 file.

Comment: What's the point of that? And compressing lossless images is pointless.The mp4 format is already designed as an efficient container. This process is slow, processor intensive, and bandwidth inefficient, etc.

Comment: It's because i need to find out differences between multiple codecs, main goal is to split 4k video into frames, compress them and send them through 1Gbit connection. So i need to find out which codec would be the best compression-wise. And as an example i have HD file on which i need to do experiments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the "detailed description" in the [muxing docs](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavf__encoding.html#ga37352ed2c63493c38219d935e71db6c1). You:

1. set ctx->[oformat](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/structAVFormatContext.html#a20d80ac07e38ff5c268d15aaf2798b98) using [av_guess_format](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavf__encoding.html#ga8795680bd7489e96eeb5aef5e615cacc)
2. set ctx->[pb](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/structAVFormatContext.html#a1e7324262b6b78522e52064daaa7bc87) using [avio_open2](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/avio_8h.html#ade8a63980569494c99593ebf0d1e891b)
3. call [avformat_new_stream](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavf__core.html#gadcb0fd3e507d9b58fe78f61f8ad39827) for each stream in the output file. If you're re-encoding, this is by adding each stream of the input file into the output file.
4. call [avformat_write_header](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavf__encoding.html#ga18b7b10bb5b94c4842de18166bc677cb)
5. call [av_interleaved_write_frame](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavf__encoding.html#ga37352ed2c63493c38219d935e71db6c1) in a loop
6. call [av_write_trailer](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavf__encoding.html#ga7f14007e7dc8f481f054b21614dfec13)
7. close the file ([avio_close](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/avio_8h.html#ad71cada104a5e4365d35d45669ea03ca)) and clear up all allocated memory

Comment: Do you know how can i copy content of `AVFrame` structure to a `char* buffer`, so i can send that buffer using winsock2's `send()` function to a different process? I'm trying to create local server-client communication to measure time needed to send a frame using different compression methods.

Comment: for (y = 0; y < height; y++) memcpy(ptr + y *width, frame->data[0] + y * frame->linesize[0], width). You can also use avcodec_encode_video2() to compress frames (instead of gzip or so, which is what you're probably trying to do).

Comment: Hmm if i do it like that rather than copying whole `AVFrame` structure, considering i'm copying raw video frames, would i be able to encode that frame (based only on `frame->data[0]` and `frame->linesize[0]`) on the recipient side using `avcodec_encode_video2()` function?

Comment: About compression, i was planning to use lzw. I will take closer look into `avcodec_encode_video2()` compression-wise. Btw, thank you for your responses i really appreciate it.

Comment: You would do the same for data[1-2] with linesize[1-2] (assuming some planar YUV format), sorry, forgot to mention that; or rather, it depends on the number of planes for your pixfmt (see pixdesc).

Comment: I succeeded sending single decoded frame from one process to another one using send/recv functions. I determined size of `char* buffer` needed to store a frame of type `PIX_FMT_RGB24` using `avpicture_get_size()`, copying `frame->data[0]` was done like this : `memcpy(buffer + y * frame->linesize[0], frame->data[0] + y*frame->linesize[0], width * 3);` and writing to a `.ppm` file on client side was done using: `fwrite(buffer + y * width * 3, 1, width * 3, pf);`. Basicly i just needed to multiply `width` from your code by 3 (since its RGB24) or use exact data stored in `frame->linesize[0]`.

Comment: I have one more question before i hopefully stop bugging you about FFmpeg, for example if i want to use LZW compression method which is already implemented in FFmpeg, how would i do it using `avcodec_encode_video2()` function? I guess i need to populate `AVCodecContext` variable with different parameters before calling the encode funtion?

Comment: ffmpeg has no vanilla lzw encoder. There's a tiff and a gif encoder, which use lzw internally...

Comment: Yea i saw tiff uses LZW internally, was hoping i could somehow implement their source into mine. Ill try to do that today.

Answer (score -2):

You can convert a video to a sequence of losses images with:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 image-%05d.png
```

and then from a series of images back to a video with:

```
ffmpeg -i image-%05d.png video.mp4
```

The functionality is also available via wrappers.

You can see a similar question at: [Extracting frames from MP4/FLV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287759/extracting-frames-from-mp4-flv)

Comment: I'm not using static build of ffmpeg, i'm using their API in my own project.

Comment: FFmpeg is the command line utility. Which library and language are you using? Libavcodec?

Comment: I'm using libavcodec/format/device/filter/util/postproc/swscale. I'm writing in C. Basicly it's an old dev build of FFmpeg.

Comment: FFmpeg is a project containing a bunch of libraries for A/V manipulation and an optional set of binaries such as ffmpeg, ffplay..etc which allow you to use the functions available in the libraries.