# Create Animated Gif From MP4 in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I would like to know if there's a way to create an animated GIF from a .mp4 file. I've researched it a bit and it seems like there is just one option:

- Creating a GIF manually by getting each frame of an .mp4 video using a `MediaPlayer`'s VideoFrameServer

I'm willing to use any open source projects that could help as well.

Comment: possible dublicae of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287759/extracting-frames-from-mp4-flv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287759/extracting-frames-from-mp4-flv) , maybe check a guide for ffmpeg